# Help me find a 1998-2000 TV series or movie about children in space with a leader who had different eye colors

Tags: story-identification

I used to watch a series around 1998-2000 about some children in space. I remember that these children are not treated well in this place they are at - a place with robots and humans/aliens, with their leader having one black eye and one kind of blue...he had two different eye colors and I think he wore blue or something like that.

One of the boys ran away (I think) and ended up in an explosion or something like that and I think he survived.

Not all of it is in space; some of the series is also on Earth. I don't remember much from it, but have been trying to find it.

There is also a girl in the movie who was hunting down some other girl on Earth.  This girl was supposed to be working for those in space or something like that.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Was it a movie or a tv series?  You mention "serie" (sic) above, and then below you mention that it is a movie.

Comment: Also might help to know what country it was from (US or UK might narrow it down for example) and whether it was live-action or cartoon :)